# JAVA get file's modified time and delete it

Tags: java, file

The folder has many files, about 100 million per folder.

For now I used the java `file.listfiles()` to get what I need, but the time is too long.
about `7~10mins` that the `listfiles()` return me the `Files[]`. This is wasting time.

Is there any better way to check every file in a folder who has a lot of files?

I am not a native speaker,sorry for any confused expressions.

Comment: Did you try a `ls` or `dir` (depending on your OS) in that folder? I'd be very surprised if that was much faster than 7-10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
Path directoryPath = Paths.get("...");
Files.find(directoryPath, 1, (p, attr) -> true)
    .foreach(Files::delete);
```

If you have a filtering condition, like `attr.creationTime()` that will be somewhat faster. Otherwise `Files.list` will do. A huge speedup one may not necessarily expect, but it could be.

Comment: it lower the program runtime from 56hs to 11hs ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DirectoryStream, path to the JavaDoc is here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-